# How can I find my home in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My 5 year old built her house and then walked away from it. Now she can't find it.

We have the game in the iPad, so there's no F3 key to hit.

How can we find our way back?

Comment: If the house was built near the world spawn you could potentially use a compass to find your way back to the area.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways, but only if the house was built near the initial spawn point.

## KILL YOURSELF

Dig a really deep hole until there aren't any blocks. Switch to survival. Log in. Switch back. If she built it near world spawn, you're good.

## COMPASS

Find one under tools and follow it. Once again, you need to have built your house near spawn

If she didn't build it near spawn, there's nothing you can do :(

Answer (score 0):

on the mcpe reddit subchannel, plethora777 has presented his (hers?) mcpe_viz application, which is capable of generating maps for MCPE world - works fabulous (albeit its a bit complicated to use), but requires a PC (win/linux/mac)

https://github.com/Plethora777/mcpe_viz is the link to the github hosting that map creator tool.